# numba jit cannot understand that single element of array is not array

Tags: arrays, casting, element, jit, numba

We are coding up a simulation for car racing for a machine learning challenge of learning to race a simulated car. As part of this we use a dynamical model for the car. It is a complicated model and needs to run in real time so I'm trying to accelerate it with numba.

I managed to solve most of the nested class object problems using fancy jitclass specs with deferred_type() instances for the arguments that are objects, but now am stumped with the following problem:

```
import numba as nb
from numba import float64 as f64  # use f64 to type explicitly for list elements to tell numba it is just scalar value
from numba import jit, deferred_type
# .... skips some lines

#consider steering constraints
pl=p.longitudinal
ps=p.steering
x3=f64(x[3])
u1=f64(uInit[1])
a=accelerationConstraints(x3,u1,pl)
```

Running this results in the following error output from numba:

```
  File "C:\Users\tobid\miniconda3\envs\l2race\lib\site-packages\numba\core\utils.py", line 81, in reraise
    raise value
numba.core.errors.LoweringError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
Cannot cast array(float64, 1d, A) to float64: %".218" = load {i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64]}, {i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64]}* %"$36binary_subscr.14"

File "commonroad\vehicleDynamics_KS.py", line 63:
def vehicleDynamics_KS(x,uInit,p):
    <source elided>
    ps=p.steering
    x3=f64(x[3])
    ^

During: lowering "$38call_function.15 = call $30load_global.11($36binary_subscr.14, func=$30load_global.11, args=[Var($36binary_subscr.14, vehicleDynamics_KS.py:63)], kws=(), vararg=None)" at F:\tobi\Dropbox (Personal)\Share Marcin Tobi\l2race\commonroad\vehicleDynamics_KS.py (63)
```

I.e., the element of uInit (which is typed as 1d vector of float32) is not treated as a float. The key error line is

> Cannot cast array(float64, 1d, A) to float64: %".218"

I.e. I take one element of uUnit, and even explicitly casting it to numba float32, the inference seems to fail.
I must be missing something.

If I change the code as follows

```
x3=x[3]
u1=uInit[1]
a=accelerationConstraints(x3,u1,pl)
```

It results in

```
Invalid use of type(CPUDispatcher(<function accelerationConstraints at 0x0000010AE7D599D8>)) with parameters (array(float64, 1d, A), array(float64, 1d, A), DeferredType#1146309640904)
Known signatures:
 * (float64, float64, DeferredType#1146309640904) -> float64
```

making it clear that numba does not correctly infer that a single element of the float32 array is a scalar float32. I.e. numba thinks I'm passing in an array of floats, not a scalar value ("*parameters (array(float64, 1d, A), array(float64, 1d, A), DeferredType#1146309640904)*")

How can I convince numba that one element of my vector is a scalar value? Or am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found out the root cause of at least this problem.
The signature of my function had been

```
fa=nb.types.List(nb.float64[:], reflected=False) # define numba type of list of float
params_type=deferred_type()
params_type.define(VehicleParameters.class_type.instance_type) # define numba type for VehicleParameters class instance that has model parameters (it also has @jitclass)

@jit(fa(fa, fa, params_type),nopython=True)
def vehicleDynamics_KS(x,uInit,p):
```

which means that I told numba I was passing in a list of a list of float, not just a list of float.

I changed my definition of float array "fa" from *fa=nb.types.List(nb.float64[:], reflected=False)* to *fa=nb.types.List(nb.float64, reflected=False)* and the signature of my method to *@jit(fa(fa, fa, params_type),nopython=True)* and now numba correctly infers the element of the list is a scalar.

There are more problems to solve but this is a step in the right direction.